# binary search (recursive) to check is if a certain value is found in a sorted array- modification

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

I studied that a recursive algorithm which checks if a certain value (key) is exists in a sorted given array, looks so:

```
int bin_search_rec(int key, int *a, int n)
{
  if (n==0)
   return 0;
  if (key=a[n/2])
   return key;
  if (key<a[n/2])
   return bin_search_rec(key,a,n/2);
  else
   return bin_search_rec(key,a+n/2 +1,n-n/2 -1 );
}
```

I also studied that this algorithm above can be modified - in order not only to check if a certain value exists in the array but also return the index of this value if it does exist - that way:

```
int bin_search_rec(int key, int *a, int n)
{
  int pos;
  if (n==0)
   return -1;
  if (key=a[n/2])
   return key;
  if (key<a[n/2])
   return bin_search_rec(key,a,n/2);
  else
   pos= bin_search_rec(key,a+n/2 +1,n-n/2 -1 );
  if (pos==-1)
   return -1;
  else
   return pos+ n/2 +1;
}
```

**I dont understand why in this modification we need to use the variable pos in order to find the index of the key.
Why is it wrong to just modify the algorithm that way instead:**

```
int bin_search_rec(int key, int *a, int n)
{
  if (n==0)
   return -1;
  if (key=a[n/2])
   return n/2;
  if (key<a[n/2])
   return bin_search_rec(key,a,n/2);
  else
   return bin_search_rec(key,a+n/2 +1,n-n/2 -1 );
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it's wrong? Seems perfectly legit to me, the first one looks weird and wrong because sometimes you return key; and sometimes you return pos+n/2+1;

Comment: The very first implementation is kind of broken, too. If you search for the value `0`, the return value is ambiguous.

Comment: If the second invocation returns a match, you need to offset it by `n/2`, otherwise you need to leave it `-1`.